# File not found issue JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have an issue with getResource() method

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        recommendations = new ArrayList<>(getRecommendations());
        for (int i = 0; i < recommendations.size(); i++) {
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("song.fxml"));
                VBox songLayout = loader.load();

                // Access the controller and set data for the song card
                SongController songController = loader.getController();
                songController.setData(recommendations.get(i));

                int row = i / 3; // Calculate row index
                int column = i % 3; // Calculate column index

                songsGrid.add(songLayout, column, row);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                // Ensure that song.fxml or songsGrid is not null
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
                // Catch any other potential exceptions
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my project structure

[image: hkj]

The error given is that the Location is not set. Is there any solution for that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other

Comment: Instead of `getClass().getResource("song.fxml")`, write `App.class.getResource("song.fxml")`, that will allow you to find the FXML in your current structure without adjusting it, if you want to keep the current structure.  The full explanation is in the duplicate.  If you also need to look up images in your current structure, you would use a different technique (absolute location), `App.class.getResource("/images/<your image file>")`;